# Resources for HF Trading of Bitcoin & Altcoin

Tags: api, altcoin, trading

I am going to write a HF trading algorithm (probably using the CCEX API) to buy sell gridcoin/altcoins.

Has anyone here got any useful resources for this? What would be the best platform to use for a beginner (CCEX API is the only one I have found)?

Related questions: [Algorithmic trading python library](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42159/algorithmic-trading-python-library) & [How to build a bitcoin trading bot?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/how-to-build-a-bitcoin-trading-bot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a bitcoin trading bot](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/how-to-build-a-bitcoin-trading-bot)

Comment: That question is for bitcoin only. It is therefore a related question not a duplicate. I have added this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my ccxt library on GitHub: https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt

With it you can access market data and trade bitcoin, ether and altcoins with many crypto currency exchanges. It provides quick access to market data for storage, analysis, visualization, indicator development, trading strategy backtesting, bot programming, building trading algorithms on top of it, webshop integration and related software engineering.

The code is in JavaScript / Python (2 and 3) / PHP. You can deploy it from PyPI, with npm (for Node.js) or by cloning from GitHub repository.

The ccxt library is under heavy development right now, but already offers a quick-start for trading and technical analysis with many crypto exchange markets out of the box.